# Find objects based on value of a key in object using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

From the json change_tasks array below I would like to extract only the values of the key "description" when the key:value is an exact match of "short_description": "01. Project validation".

```
{
    "change_tasks": [{
        "active": "true",
        "approval": "Not Yet Requested", 
        "description": "testing",
        "short_description": "Test description",
        "state": "-5",
        "state_description": "Pending",
        "sys_class_name": "Change Task",
        "sys_created_on": "2023-05-10 15:23:50",
        "sys_updated_on": "2023-05-10 15:25:58",
        "time_worked": "",
        "u_actions_taken_to_prevent_recurrence": "",
        "u_createdby_businessappid": ""
    }, 
    {
        "active": "true",
        "approval": "Not Yet Requested",
        "description": "value-01, value-02",
        "short_description": "01. Project validation",
        "state": "-5",
        "state_description": "Pending",
        "sys_class_name": "Change Task",
        "sys_created_on": "2023-05-10 15:21:01",
        "sys_updated_on": "2023-05-10 15:25:58",
        "time_worked": "",
        "u_actions_taken_to_prevent_recurrence": "",
        "u_createdby_businessappid": ""
    }],
    "responseSummary": {
        "message": "Search successfully executed",
        "code": "200",
        "businessUnit": "unit1",
        "businessAppId": "123456",
        "numRecordsReturned": "2",
        "totalRecords": "2",
        "hasMore": "false"
    }
}
```

This query gives me the output of the correct change task but I only require the values of "description" when "short_description" is "01. Project validation". Also  the change tasks value I want will not always be [1] it could be any in the list of objects.

```
$ jq -r .change_tasks[1].short_description test.json
01. Project validation
```

I will then need to turn the comma separated values of "description" into variables so they can be checked against another list of values in bash.

Comment: Something involving `select(.short_description = "01. Project validation")`?

Comment: If "checking against another list of values" also happens to be a JSON-based operation in jq, you might want to consider moving also the intermediate Bash logic into jq, so that you could end up calling jq just once with all files involved as arguments, which in the end is usually more efficient than having a lookup in jq, a loop in Bash, followed by one or more extractions in jq again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
$ jq -r '.change_tasks[] | select(.short_description == "01. Project validation").description | gsub(",\\s+";",") | split(",") | @sh ' test.json
'value-01' 'value-02'
```

if you want to read this into two variables:

```bash
function get_values {
    jq -r '.change_tasks[] | select(.short_description == "01. Project validation").description | gsub(",\\s+";",") | split(",") | @sh ' test.json
}

read value1 value2<<<$(get_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sorting it myself like this in the end

```
#!/bin/sh

variable=$(jq -r '.change_tasks[] | select(.short_description=="01. Project validation").description' test.json)

for i in ${variable//,/ }
do
    # call your procedure/other scripts here below
    echo "$i"
done
```